# Navigation stack yellow warning triangle

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, ios16

I'm attempting to listen for a change in a boolean value & changing the view once it has been heard which it does successfully, however, results in a yellow triangle. I haven't managed to pinpoint the issue but it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the view that it's transitioning to as even when changed the error still persists.

My code is below

```
import SwiftUI

struct ConversationsView: View {
    @State var isShowingNewMessageView = false
    @State var showChat = false
    @State var root = [Root]()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $root) {
            ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
                ScrollView {
                    LazyVStack {
                        ForEach(0 ..< 20) { _ in
                            Text("Test")
                        }
                    }
                }.padding()
            }

            Button {
                self.isShowingNewMessageView.toggle()
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "plus.message.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .renderingMode(.template)
                    .frame(width: 48, height: 48)
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                    .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingNewMessageView, content: {
                        NewMessageView(show: $isShowingNewMessageView, startChat: $showChat)
                    })
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: showChat) { newValue in
            guard newValue else { return }
            root.append(.profile)
        }.navigationDestination(for: Root.self) { navigation in
            switch navigation {
            case .profile:
                ChatView()
            }
        }
    }

    enum Root {
        case profile
    }
}
```

ChatView() Code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ChatView: View {
    @State var messageText: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 12) {
                    ForEach(MOCK_MESSAGES) { message in
                        MessageView(message: message)
                    }
                }
            }.padding(.top)

            MessageInputView(messageText: $messageText)
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Any support is much appreciated.

Comment: What does the issue say?

Comment: @MrDeveloper There's no issue it is literally just switches the view to a yellow warning triangle.

Comment: Well, the problem must be in your "ChatView()" - please provide the code for that view.

Comment: @bjorn.lau edited with code !

Comment: I very much believe  that problem is with `navigationDestination` modifier place, it should be inside NavigationStack`. `NavigationStack` always shows when it can't find suitable View for path. Please, check my answer

Answer (score 16):

You should use `navigationDestination` modifier inside your `NavigationStack` component, just move it.

```swift
NavigationStack(path: $root) {
    ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
        
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(0..<20) { _ in
                    Text("Test")
                }
            }
        }.padding()
    }.navigationDestination(for: Root.self) { navigation in
        switch navigation {
        case .profile:
            ChatView()
        }
    }

  //...
}
```

Basically this yellow triangle means `NavigationStack` can't find suitable component for path. And when you using `navigationDestination` directly on `NavigationStack` View or somewhere outside it is ignored

Comment: It seems to work when the navigationDestination is attached directly on NavigationStack inside NavigationSplitView's detail closure (on iPadOS).

Answer (score 1):

You must set .environmentObject(root) to NavigationStack in order to provide the NavigationPath to the view subhierarchy (ChatView in your case). Also you must have a @EnvironmentObject property of type Root in your ChatView so that it can read the path.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I get the error: Instance method 'environmentObject' requires that '[ConversationsView.Root]' conform to 'ObservableObject'

Comment: you could try having a class that conforms to ObservableObject and that holds a NavigationPath instead of an enum. The response from Evgeny is also correct, you should not use .navigationDestination directly on the NavigationStack, but inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use NavigationDestination directly in NavigationStack. You need to inject it into the first View object in the NavigationStack. The code block is below as an example.

```
struct BaseTabView: View {

@State private var path = NavigationPath()
@State private var selection = 1

var body: some View {
    NavigationStack(path: $path) {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            HomeView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
                }
                .tag(1)
            
            HistoryView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("History", systemImage: "clock.arrow.circlepath")
                }
                .tag(2)
        }
        .tint(.red)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                HStack {
                    Button("", systemImage: "star.square.on.square.fill") {
                        path.append(HomeNavigation.paywall)
                    }
                    .tint(Color.brandColor)
                    Button("", systemImage: "gearshape.fill") {
                        path.append(HomeNavigation.settings)
                    }
                    .tint(Color.brandColor)
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle(TabItem(rawValue: selection)?.navigationTitle ?? "")
        .navigationDestination(for: HomeNavigation.self) { navigation in
            switch navigation {
            case .paywall:
                SettingsView()
            case .settings:
                SettingsView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```