# navigationDestination was declared earlier on the stack

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

I'm running into an issue with `.navigationDestination`. When the user clicks the Calculate button, a new view opens with a list of the items. Then the user can click on a row and get more details. However, it shows a new list with items instead, with the following error in the console:

> A navigationDestination for “testApp.Item” was declared earlier on the stack. Only the destination declared closest to the root view of the stack will be used.

In fact, if you look closely, the details show briefly and then the list is shown again.

I have been trying to find a solution for a while now, and there are many similar questions, and the answer is always `.navigationDestination` should be as high in the hierarchy as possible, which I think is the case in my code.

So something else must be going on, but I am lost.

What am I missing here?

Here is a MRE:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Calculator {
    let items = [
        Item(name: "One", number: 1),
        Item(name: "Two", number: 2),
        Item(name: "Three", number: 3)
    ]
}

struct Item: Hashable {
    var name: String
    var number: Int
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var didCalculate = false
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()

    let calculator = Calculator()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            Button("Calculate") {
                // in real app a long calculation here inside a Task
                didCalculate = true
            }
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $didCalculate) {
                ItemsView(items: calculator.items)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ItemsView: View {
    var items: [Item]

    var body: some View {
        List(items, id: \.self) { item in
            NavigationLink(value: item) {
                Text(item.name)
            }
        }
        .navigationDestination(for: Item.self) { item in
            ItemDetailView(item: item)
        }
    }
}

struct ItemRow: View {
    var item: Item

    var body: some View {
        Text(item.name)
    }
}

struct ItemDetailView: View {
    var item: Item

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(item.name)
            Text(String(item.number))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience, `.navigationDestination(isPresented:destination:)` doesn't mix well with value-based navigation. If the `isPresented` binding is till true when you navigate to another view with a value, the destination will be pushed onto the stack again. This is possibly why SwiftUI is saying the destination for `Item.self` is already declared earlier in the stack. "Earlier" is when `ItemsView` first gets added to the stack, and `ItemsView` is now getting added to the stack again, redeclaring the same navigation destination for `Item.self`.

The destinations added this way also doesn't affect the navigation path, making it more annoying to use with value-based navigation.

I would also use value-based navigation to navigate to `ItemsView`. You can declare a new dummy struct/enum to use as the destination's type. If you have multiple destinations, an enum would be more convenient.

```
struct ItemsViewDestination: Hashable {}

var body: some View {
    NavigationStack(path: $path) {
        Button("Calculate") {
            // navigate like this:
            path.append(ItemsViewDestination())
        }
        .navigationDestination(for: ItemsViewDestination.self) { _ in
            ItemsView(items: calculator.items)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, in the MRE this works. But In my app, which has more views, I now get a yellow triangle in `ItemsView`. Is that because I only use `path.append` in this case, but not the complete hierarchy?

Comment: @koen The question doesn't involve any yellow triangles, so it would be hard for me to debug this. Use the UI debugger to see what the yellow triangle actually is. I suspect it is caused by some other parts of your code.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74540293/navigation-stack-yellow-warning-triangle for the yellow triangle.

Comment: @koen Ummm, so that answered your question or what? I understand what the yellow triangle is now, but you would need to provide a [mcve] that reproduces it if the post you linked didn't help you. I would suggest asking a new question, instead of making this post a chameleon question.

Answer (score 0):

So just for completeness, here is my final code, based on @Sweeper's accepted answer, but now using an enum for two navigation destinations, which solved the 'yellow triangle' issue.

For a larger app, there will be many enum cases though.

Hopefully this is helpful for any other readers.

```
import SwiftUI

enum Route: Hashable {
    case calculator
    case items([Item])
}

struct Item: Hashable {
    var name: String
    var number: Int
}

struct Calculator {
    let items = [
        Item(name: "One", number: 1),
        Item(name: "Two", number: 2),
        Item(name: "Three", number: 3)
    ]
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(value: Route.calculator) {
                    Text("Intermediate")
                }
            
                NavigationLink(destination: DummyView()) {
                    Text("Dummy")
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Route.self) { route in
                switch route {
                case .calculator:
                    CalculatorView(path: $path)
                case let .items(items):
                    ItemsView(items: items)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CalculatorView: View {
    @Binding var path: NavigationPath

    let calculator = Calculator()

    var body: some View {
        Button("Calculate") {
            // in real app a long calculation here inside Task
            path.append(Route.items(calculator.items))
        }
    }
}

struct ItemsView: View {
    var items: [Item]

    var body: some View {
        List(items, id: \.self) { item in
            NavigationLink(destination: ItemDetailView(item: item)) {
                Text(item.name)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ItemDetailView: View {
    var item: Item

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(item.name)
            Text(String(item.number))
        }
    }
}

struct DummyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Just a dummy view that doesn't do anything")
    }
}
```