Yellow Warning Triangle When Trying to .append to NavigationPath
I am trying to navigate to another view after my function returns a CloudKit record (which is triggered by a user tapping a button), however upon testing, and successful retrieval of said record, the screen displays a yellow warning triangle ⚠️, and does not navigate to the ProfileView.
This is a simplified version of my code:
@State var invites: [CKRecord] = []
@State private var path = NavigationPath()

var body: some View {
    NavigationStack (path: $path) {
        List {
            
            ForEach(invites, id: \.recordID) { invite in
                
                if let acceptedBy = invite["acceptedInvite"] as? CKRecord.Reference {
                    Button(action: {
                        
                        fetchUserAccount(userToFetch: acceptedBy) { accountRecord in
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                
                                if accountRecord != nil {
                                    path.append(accountRecord) // Works, but causes ⚠️ to show on screen
                                }
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }, label: {
                        Text("\(invite.recordID.recordName)")
                    })
                }
            }
            
        }
    }.navigationDestination(for: CKRecord.self) { record in
        ProfileView(profileRecord: record)
    }
}

As mentioned, I'm trying to present ProfileView(profileRecord: record), however instead, no error is shown in the logs, however the main view is removed and a yellow warning triangle ⚠️ gets displayed instead.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74540293/navigation-stack-yellow-warning-triangle

Did you find a solution to this?

move your .navigationDestination(...) inside the NavigationStack, just after List.
you also need to ensure that accountRecord is of type CKRecord not Optional CKRecord, that is
try path.append(accountRecord!)

Tried that, made no difference.

Thank you, this has resolved this problem, however a new issue has resulted it now just pops back to the previous view instead of opening the Profile view.

Without a minimal code that we can compile and run, it is difficult to find the cause of your new issue.

Okay thank you, I will dig more into this issue and post a new question.

I had this popping back thing as well, not fixed yet. The console could be more informative with this.

This did not work for me, I get the following error:
The navigationDestination modifier only works inside a NavigationStack or NavigationSplitView. There's a misplaced navigationDestination(for:destination:) modifier for type xxx. It will be ignored.

As I said in my answer "move your .navigationDestination(...) inside the NavigationStack", and as the error tells you, you are not doing this. Look carefully at all the curly braces.
